# Java: Usar GET y POST en el mismo Form

Tags: javascript, java, post, servlets, get

Lo que quiero hacer es mandar los parametros del `Form` al `POST` y luego atraves del metodo `GET` consultar a la `BBDD` por disponibilidad de habitaciones y mandar ese resultado atraves `Ajax` (Vanilla Javascript) al `HTML`. Pero por lo que estuve viendo no puedo usar los metodos al mismo tiempo. Solo funciona si uso solo el metodo `POST` (method="POST") o solo el metodo `GET` (method="GET") en el Form.

Aca la consulta `Ajax`:

```
function loadDoc() {
                var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhttp.open("GET", "Controlador", true);
                xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
                xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
                        document.getElementById("precio").innerHTML = this.responseText;

                    }
                };

                xhttp.send();
                //document.getElementsByTagName("FORM").submit();
            }
```

Y aca el metodo `doGet`:

```
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        ReservaDAOImp rv = new ReservaDAOImp();

        rsv.setTipoHab(request.getParameter("tipHab"));
        rsv.setCodHotel(request.getParameter("hoteles"));
        out.print(rv.disponibilidad("select disponibilidad from T_tiphab where tipo=? and codHotel=?", rsv));
```

> Cuando uso el metodo `GET` en el `Form` me envia a otra pagina con el
>   resultado correcto pero cuando lo uso con `Ajax` los parametros del
>   formulario llegan `NULL` al Servlet.

Comment: Creo que estas un poco confundido amigo, con ambos métodos, `GET` y `POST` puedes enviar y recibir datos, pero `GET` está pensado para obtener páginas acorde a una información que envíes mientras que `POST` está pensado para enviar información a ser evaluada o recibir información adecuada a lo que necesites ya sea de una base de datos u otro.

Comment: Yo con el `POST` inserto en la base de datos, luego quiero hacer un `GET` que me calcule, en este caso, la disponibilidad de las habitaciones en base a lo posteado  a traves de `AJAX`. Pero en la pagina HTML no puedo hacer las dos cosas al mismo tiempo.

Comment: Entonces eso significa que estas aprovechando el auto submit del form, por lo que puedes capturar este evento y hacer algo mas en el. te lo muestro en una respuesta

Comment: Porque al mismo tiempo? No puedes primero hacer un POST y luego un GET?

Comment: Si.pero como..no puedo hacerlo dinámicamente.. quiero mandar los datos por POST y luego hacer un GET en la misma página con AJAX ..

Answer (score 1):

Básicamente lo que debes hacer es capturar el evento submit del form y hacer algo en el.
A modo de ejemplo mostraremos el siguiente form

```
<form action="/action_page.php" method="post" onsubmit="funcionAdicional()">
...
</form>
<script>
    function funcionAdicional(){
        // ejecutar función  GET
        ...
    }
</script>
```

Al agregar el controlador de evento `onsubmit`  puedes ejecutar código cuando el formulario es enviado.

Answer (score 0):

Veo que la pregunta es algo antigua pero a alguien le podría servir la respuesta.

Lo que  puede hacer es que en el método de envío lo hace por post `method="post"` y en action le escribe la url a la que quiere enviar y le pasa parámetros por ahí, algo así: `action="la-url.php?param=2019"`.